# What is the optimum speed for takeoff flaps?

Tags: aircraft-performance, takeoff, boeing-737, flaps

I took a 737 rating written test yesterday and one of the questions was:

What's the optimum speed for takeoff flaps?

1. V2
2. V2 + 10
3. V2 + 15
4. V2 + 20

Anybody knows the answer? I did some research and couldn't find it.

Comment: Optimum for what? Climb gradient, rate of climb, engine-out climb, schedule?

Comment: @Sami I have no idea. This was the exact wording of the question as far as I remember.

Comment: FWIW, the webpage at http://www.flaps2approach.com/journal/2014/8/4/boeing-737-800-takeoff-procedure-simplified.html has the statement, "V2+15/20 is the optimum climb speed with takeoff flaps.  It results in maximum altitude gain in the shortest distance from takeoff."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I assume the question means optimum **climb** speed.*

From the Boeing 737 NG FCTM (3.30 Takeoff and Initial Climb):

> V2 + 20 is the optimum climb speed with takeoff flaps. It results in the maximum
>   altitude gain in the shortest distance from takeoff. Acceleration to higher speeds
>   reduces the altitude gain. If airspeed exceeds V2 + 20 during the initial climb, stop
>   the acceleration but do not attempt to reduce airspeed to V2 + 20. Any speed
>   between V2 + 15 and V2 + 25 knots results in approximately the same takeoff
>   profile. Crosscheck indicated airspeed for proper initial climb speed.